# Joining on windowed function to show the next date in relation to ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a query I am putting together, but I am struglling to join the sequence generated by a windowed function in POSTGRESQL

```
 SELECT e.start_time, ne.start_time, e.end_time
    FROM
        (SELECT e.ID, e.start_time, e.end_time, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.ID ORDER BY e.start_time) AS "SEQ"
        FROM events e
        )e
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT ne.ID, ne.start_time, ne.end_time, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ne.ID ORDER BY ne.start_time) AS "nSEQ" 
        FROM events ne
        )ne
    ON e.ID = ne.ID
    AND e.SEQ = ne.nSEQ - 1
```

In SQL server this would have done just fine, but it appears POSTGRESQL does not like this way of joining for some reason. Could someone advise on another approach?

I expect to see the preceding event_start and the next event_start on the same row relative to the ID

Comment: Couldn't you just use `LEAD(start_time) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY start_time)`?

Comment: Will this provide the next start time relative to the ID on the same row?

Comment: It should, yes.  Something like: `SELECT start_time, LEAD(start_time) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY start_time), end_time FROM events;`  I'm not sure what error you were getting before but it may have been due to the double quotes you used.  If you use them in one place, you'll need to use them everywhere, so your join condition should be `AND e."SEQ" = ne."nSEQ" - 1` but using lead is better anyway.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @Jeremy fantastic much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell us the error you get, but I guess it's something about an invalid identifier.

You are mixing quoted identifiers (= case **sensitive**) with non-quoted identifiers (= case **insensitive**).

As [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) (and required by the SQL standard), `"nSEQ"` is a different name than `nSEQ`.  My recommendation is: remove double quotes from all your SQL statements entirely, then you will never have a problem.

The following should work just fine:

```
SELECT e.start_time, ne.start_time, e.end_time
FROM (
  SELECT e.ID, e.start_time, e.end_time, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.ID ORDER BY e.start_time) AS SEQ --<< no quotes!
  FROM events e
) e 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ne.ID, ne.start_time, ne.end_time, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ne.ID ORDER BY ne.start_time) AS nSEQ --<< no quotes
    FROM events ne
  ) ne ON e.ID = ne.ID AND e.SEQ = ne.nSEQ - 1;
```

---

Unrelated, but: that is a quite inefficient way of getting the "next" value. Use the lead() function instead and you can get rid of the whole join completely:

```
SELECT e.start_time, 
       lead(e.end_time) over (PARTITION BY e.ID ORDER BY e.start_time) as next_end_time, 
       e.end_time, 
FROM events e
```